# Getting problem with heroku db:push

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am making my first test on heroku and I have problem with the heroku db:push.
my config :

```
ruby 1.8.7 (2009-06-12 patchlevel 174) [i686-darwin9.8.0]
gem 1.3.7
```

Is someone can help me ?

```
$ heroku db:push

Loaded Taps v0.3.12
Auto-detected local database: mysql://root@localhost/siftest?encoding=utf8
Warning: Data in the app 'morning-waterfall-18' will be overwritten and will not be recoverable.
Are you sure you wish to continue? (y/n)? y
Sending schema
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.12/bin/schema:3:in `require': no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)
 from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.12/bin/schema:3
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.12/bin/schema:3:in `require': no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)
 from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.12/bin/schema:3
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.12/bin/schema:3:in `require': no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)
 from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.12/bin/schema:3
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.12/bin/schema:3:in `require': no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)
 from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.12/bin/schema:3
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.12/bin/schema:3:in `require': no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)
 from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.12/bin/schema:3
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.12/bin/schema:3:in `require': no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)
 from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.12/bin/schema:3
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.12/bin/schema:3:in `require': no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)
 from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.12/bin/schema:3
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.12/bin/schema:3:in `require': no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)
 from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.12/bin/schema:3
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.12/bin/schema:3:in `require': no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)
 from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.12/bin/schema:3
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.12/bin/schema:3:in `require': no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)
 from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.12/bin/schema:3
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.12/bin/schema:3:in `require': no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)
 from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.12/bin/schema:3
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.12/bin/schema:3:in `require': no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)
 from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.12/bin/schema:3
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.12/bin/schema:3:in `require': no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)
 from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.12/bin/schema:3
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.12/bin/schema:3:in `require': no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)
 from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.12/bin/schema:3
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.12/bin/schema:3:in `require': no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)
 from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.12/bin/schema:3
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.12/bin/schema:3:in `require': no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)
 from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.12/bin/schema:3
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.12/bin/schema:3:in `require': no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)
 from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.12/bin/schema:3
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.12/bin/schema:3:in `require': no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)
 from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.12/bin/schema:3
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.12/bin/schema:3:in `require': no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)
 from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.12/bin/schema:3
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.12/bin/schema:3:in `require': no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)
 from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.12/bin/schema:3
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.12/bin/schema:3:in `require': no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)
 from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.12/bin/schema:3
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.12/bin/schema:3:in `require': no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)
 from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.12/bin/schema:3
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.12/bin/schema:3:in `require': no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)
 from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.12/bin/schema:3
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.12/bin/schema:3:in `require': no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)
 from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.12/bin/schema:3
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.12/bin/schema:3:in `require': no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)
 from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.12/bin/schema:3
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.12/bin/schema:3:in `require': no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)
 from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.12/bin/schema:3
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.12/bin/schema:3:in `require': no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)
 from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.12/bin/schema:3
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.12/bin/schema:3:in `require': no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)
 from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.12/bin/schema:3
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.12/bin/schema:3:in `require': no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)
 from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.12/bin/schema:3
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.12/bin/schema:3:in `require': no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)
 from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.12/bin/schema:3
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.12/bin/schema:3:in `require': no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)
 from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.12/bin/schema:3
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.12/bin/schema:3:in `require': no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)
 from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.12/bin/schema:3
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.12/bin/schema:3:in `require': no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)
 from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.12/bin/schema:3
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.12/bin/schema:3:in `require': no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)
 from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.12/bin/schema:3
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.12/bin/schema:3:in `require': no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)
 from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.12/bin/schema:3
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.12/bin/schema:3:in `require': no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)
 from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.12/bin/schema:3
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.12/bin/schema:3:in `require': no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)
 from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.12/bin/schema:3
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.12/bin/schema:3:in `require': no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)
 from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.12/bin/schema:3
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.12/bin/schema:3:in `require': no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)
 from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.12/bin/schema:3
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.12/bin/schema:3:in `require': no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)
 from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.12/bin/schema:3
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.12/bin/schema:3:in `require': no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)
 from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.12/bin/schema:3
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.12/bin/schema:3:in `require': no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)
 from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.12/bin/schema:3
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.12/bin/schema:3:in `require': no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)
 from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.12/bin/schema:3
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.12/bin/schema:3:in `require': no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)
 from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.12/bin/schema:3
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.12/bin/schema:3:in `require': no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)
 from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.12/bin/schema:3
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.12/bin/schema:3:in `require': no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)
 from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.12/bin/schema:3
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.12/bin/schema:3:in `require': no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)
 from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.12/bin/schema:3
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.12/bin/schema:3:in `require': no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)
 from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.12/bin/schema:3
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.12/bin/schema:3:in `require': no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)
 from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.12/bin/schema:3
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.12/bin/schema:3:in `require': no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)
 from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.12/bin/schema:3
Schema:        100% |==========================================| Time: 00:00:24
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.12/bin/schema:3:in `require': no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)
 from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.12/bin/schema:3
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/json_pure-1.4.6/lib/json/pure/parser.rb:148:in `parse': source did not contain any JSON! (JSON::ParserError)
 from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/json_pure-1.4.6/lib/json/common.rb:146:in `parse'
 from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.12/lib/taps/operation.rb:410:in `push_indexes'
 from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.12/lib/taps/operation.rb:388:in `run'
 from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.12/lib/taps/cli.rb:169:in `clientxfer'
 from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/heroku-1.10.5/lib/heroku/commands/db.rb:162:in `taps_client'
 from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/heroku-1.10.5/lib/heroku/commands/db.rb:13:in `push'
 from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/heroku-1.10.5/lib/heroku/command.rb:48:in `send'
 from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/heroku-1.10.5/lib/heroku/command.rb:48:in `run_internal'
 from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/heroku-1.10.5/lib/heroku/command.rb:20:in `run'
 from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/heroku-1.10.5/bin/heroku:13
 from /usr/bin/heroku:19:in `load'
 from /usr/bin/heroku:19
```

Comment: Did you uninstall rubygems? Can you do `gem --version` in terminal?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the no such file to load rubygems error, which could mean this: 
3.3 No such file to load -- rubygems
When I run the gem command, I get the following error message:

ruby: No such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)
What’s wrong?

Answer
It looks like executing copy of Ruby does not have the RubyGems library installed. RubyGems was probably installed at one time (because the gem command is recognized), but it may have been installed on a different installation of Ruby than the one you are currently running.

Things to check
Check that the installation of Ruby that is running is the same one that has RubyGems installed. On a unix system, the which command (or type command) will help figure this out.
Verify that the currently running installation of Ruby does indeed have the RubyGems library installed. You should find a “rubygems.rb” file in the site_ruby/1.8 directory of the Ruby installation.
These mixup can easily happen after installing a new instance of Ruby, but the old instance preceeds the new one in the PATH list.

That information can be found here: http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/19

Comment: I do not have the problem anymore, but I don't know why. I think my RoR cofiguration wasn't stable. But know it's ok the heroku db:push worked. Thank you for your answer